# Maintain selection of external HDMI monitor

Tags: windows, hdmi, laptop-display

I currently have my laptop connected to my (external) HDMI monitor through a HDMI switcher. When the switcher is changed from the HDMI channel of my laptop, the laptop detects it as a disconnect monitor event and switches back to its (built-in) display. I don't want that. I want it to continue to output through HDMI. Is this possible? if so, how? Assume I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution might be to check your BIOS and see if you can't hard set your default display to HDMI. If there is a setting (in your BIOS) then that's about all there is to it. Problem is, BIOS's don't usually have this. (I've only seen it on a few HP systems and once on a DEll).

Therefore, I would suggest checking your video drivers, first to see if you have the most up to date drivers and then see if this ability isn't in there by tweaking the settings. You may even have to install/update your motherboards own chipset drivers just so Windows can properly detect your video chipset.

NVidia, ATI and Intel may all have the ability to redirect or hard set certain outputs by tweaking the video driver of newer hardware at least. But I'd be willing to bet that it's not an easy thing to find since a setting like that is likely going to be in an advanced menu somewhere - assuming if it's even available.

But since I don't know the make and model of your laptop or what video card/adapter you have then that's about the best I can do.

However! There may be a hardware cable fix I'm unaware of. There may even be a product! But that solution is likely going to require manipulation of various HDMI signals (found on the different HDMI pins). Then again, you may already have this in your existing HDMI switch and it may simply just be a matter of enabling it. Have you looked?! (Again, I have no idea what switch you use or I might be able to help more.)

Sorry if that's not very helpful. But at least it's a general direction.

Comment: I have a HP dv7 with the latest Intel x64 video drivers. as for the switch, it's just a cheap one off of amazon found here:http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0015YWKYY/ref=oh_details_o02_s00_i00

Answer (score 0):

No. The HDMI switch does a "hard" disconnect/connect of the HDMI display. Most devices don't care, since they blast away through their HDMI port regardless. For devices that detect the link status, this can cause issues as you've already seen. The only fix for this is to get a HDMI switch that "ghosts" the HDMI display on all input ports (no, I don't know of any that do this).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues with my digital signage players.  You can purchase an additional piece of hardware that will maintain that connection for the computer.  [Check this product out](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=688519&gclid=CJ6e5aH__r4CFZSEfgodE54Akw&is=REG&Q=&A=details)

When will this be available as a standard feature of the video output hardware?  My guess is the more this issue is brought up in the world and to the correct people that can implement it, then we will see them more and more.  Digital outputs are here to stay, we need this for embedded hardware in the world that isn't just a laptop or computer at a desk.